# How do I reference Django 1.5 URLs that are "named" in an included URL file?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have my project's main urls.py file with the following:

```
 url(r'^accounts/$', include('accounts.urls'),
```

In accounts.urls.py, I have the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('accounts.views',
    url(r'^profile/$', 'accounts_profile', name='accounts_profile'),
```

In my base.html template, I have:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'accounts_profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
```

This results in a ReverseNotFound error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'accounts_profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

If I move the accounts_profile url definition to the main urls.py, the URL works. I remember this style of URL organization working in a prior Django version; has something changed, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the $ in your `url(r'^accounts/$', include('accounts.urls'),` call.

> Note that the regular expressions in this example don’t have a $ (end-of-string match character) but do include a trailing slash.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: Here I was thinking Django 1.5 changes things!  Thanks for the help!